# How to return a partial view based on div id?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my page I have loaded many partial views and i have used tabs for this. I have used tabs. so that each div appears as seperate page.
like

```
<div id="1">
@Html.Patrial("_Address")
</div>
<div id="2">
@Html.Patrial("_ContactDetails")
</div>
```

How to return a partial view based on div id from controller different action method

Comment: `@Html.Patrial(..)` is misspelled, it should be `@Html.Partial(..)` And make sure your PartialViews is correctly named according to the view you're passing in from your Index. Your Controller should look something like `public ActionResult Index() { return View(); }`

Comment: try this $('{div id}').load('/{Controller name}/{action}')